# Rails 3.1 ajax:success handling

Tags: ajax, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So Im playing with CoffeeScript, Rails 3.1 all the good stuff. I have a resource with all the usual routes index, show, create, edit, update, destroy.

The index view has a form that uses `:remote => true` like so:

```
<%= form_for @todo, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the controller for create I have the following:

```
def create
    @todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @todo, status: :created, location: @todo }
        format.js {render json: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Im trying to not use .js.erb views as I would rather handle the JSON returned and do all the fancy appends to the todo list and so on. (It just feels cleaner to me).

In my todos.js.coffee I have used the following:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $("#new_todo")
      .bind "ajax:success", (event, data) ->
        alert("Ajax SUCCESS!!!")
```

(Yeah just tyting to open an alert box does not work) I tried loads but just cannot trigger this event. The request does complete successfully and the new todo is added.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You might have a look in Firebug to see what the XHR conversation is. That might shed some light on what is coming back from your app.

Comment: Yeah, sorry should have said I'm getting back what I expect, the JSON of the freshly created todo item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Started to pour over the rails.js and wondered if any of the ajax: callbacks were being raise.

Turned out they were well the beforeSend and error... hang on... error? How could this be? The creation of the new todo happens successfully, the response is the JSON I expect. But on stepping through the callback code I notice an `Invalid label` error.

Quick google later brings me to this post http://blog.seqmedia.com/?p=484

Turns out the JSON is being returned as a string, Firbug got that and parsed it correctly so I could check the response. However rails.js and js in general didnt know how to handle the string and threw the above error (rather silently I may say).

The solution was in the respond_to

```
format.js {render json: @todo, content_type: 'text/json' }
```

A bit thanks to Trevor Burnham (like the book BTW) for his help and Amy from [sequence media](http://www.seqmedia.com/) whose blog post ultimately gave me the solution.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you saved me. I was having the exact same problem and was completely stuck. Why on earth does rails not render json as json by default??

Answer (score -1):

1. What is `#new_todo`? Does an element with that ID exist? Verify that `$('#new_todo').length > 0` in your code, and that it's the right element to bind your event handler to.
2. What is `ajax:success`? The jQuery API defines an `ajaxSuccess` event (see the [Ajax Events docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events)), but I've never seen the version with the colon before.

Comment: #new_todo is the id of the form that the todo item is created from, I am sure this exists. as for the ajax:success this is from the rails.js aka jquery_ujs added by default for all Rails3+ applications

Comment: Hmm, so what happens if you bind an alert callback to the form's `'submit'` event?

Comment: Hmmm something iffy, nothing happens. v.strange ill look into the coffeescript

Comment: Even stranger, I removed coffeescript from the equation (temporarily) and added the bind to the submit in js in the application.js file and still nothing. $('#new_todo').submit(function() { alert("hello"); });

Comment: Right, there's nothing wrong with your CoffeeScripting. I'd again ask if you're sure that the form's id is `#new_todo`. What is `console.log $('#new_todo').length`? What happens if you bind the `submit` callback and then call `.submit()` to trigger it?

Comment: Changed my coffeescript to `jQuery -> console.log $('#new_form').length` and returns 1 as expected. The submit works as expected now however the ajax:success getting called