# Coffeescript not handling ajax:success

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As [I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13310341/306084) in a question last week, I'm working with [@coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203130/coreyward)'s [excellent walk-through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5766232/306084) for modal edit windows in Rails 3. However, I'm a relative novice with Coffeescript, and I'm having trouble with the code which is supposed to display the modal window on a successful Ajax response. This is the relevant function (drawn from [Corey's gist](https://gist.github.com/1456815)):

```
$ ->
  $modal = $('#modal')
  $modal_close = $modal.find('.close')
  $modal_container = $('#modal-container')

  # Handle modal links with the data-remote attribute
  $(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a[data-remote]', (xhr, data, status) ->
    $modal
      .html(data)
      .prepend($modal_close)
      .css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 40)
      .show()
    $modal_container.show();

  $(document).on 'click', '#modal .close', ->
    $modal_container.hide()
    $modal.hide()
    false
```

I've established that all the code inside the function works; it just never gets called. I can see the Ajax query in the Chrome network panel, and verify that it returns a proper response.

I simplified the code to pop up an alert on an `ajax:success` event:

```
  $(document).on 'ajax:success', () -> 
    alert('Ajax success event!')
```

...and nothing. So I think the `ajax:success' event is never happening.

Trying to extract the simplest possible code that duplicates the problem, I set up [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/GdNKn/) with the following code:

`<a href="javascript:$.ajax('/echo/js/?delay=2&js=WHEEEEE!');" data-remote="true">Edit</a>​`

```
$(document).on 'ajax:success', () -> 
  alert('Ajax success event!')
```

​
...yeah. Nothing. The jsFiddle Ajax echo returns what it should, but the function never gets called. So I'm doing something wrong with `.on('ajax:success')`. (This is sort of the opposite problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13017890/306084), so that answer isn't helpful. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598137/306084), about the mime-type of the response, looks promising, but doesn't explain why the jsFiddle doesn't work, because that doesn't touch my controllers.) What is it?

ETA: I should probably mention the stack involved here. *facepalm*

- Rails 3.2.8
- jquery-rails 2.1.3
- ...which means jQuery 1.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it. I needed to make two changes:

- First, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598137/306084), I needed to be returning a `text/json` MIME type on the response. My action previously looked like this:

```rb
  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

To get a `text/json` response I wound up with this:

```rb
  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :json => { :html => render_to_string('edit')}, :content_type => 'text/json' }
      format.html
    end
  end
```

That change triggered `ajax:success` and therefore ran the open-modal functions.

- However, because the response payload was now in `data.html` rather than just `data`, I needed to tweak the `modal.js.coffee` to actually put markup in the modal:

```
  .html(data.html) // instead of .html(data)
```